# Prioritise which identifier to use

Tags: crystal-reports

My crystal report pulls data about books, including an identifier (isbn, issn order number etc.), author, and publisher.

The ID field stores multiple ways to identify the book. The report displays any of the identifiers for that record. If one book has two identifiers; issn and order number, the report currently displays one apparently at random.

How can I make it prioritise which type to use based on a preset order? I figured some sort of filter on the field could work, but I haven't figured out how. I can't edit the table, but I can use SQL within the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the different types of ID are stored in a single field, your best bet is to use a SQL Command inside your report to separate them into multiple virtual fields.

Go to Database Fields / Database Expert, expand the connection you want to use, and pick Add Command. From here you can write a custom SQL statement to grab the information you're currently using, and at the same time separate the ID field into multiple different fields (as far as the report will be concerned, anyway. The table will stay unchanged.)

The trick is to figure out how to write your command to do the separation. We don't know what your data looks like, so you're on your own from here.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to achieve this in SQL but was hoping that it could be achieved in the field i.e. by adding a formula to the field. I'll keep trying :)

Comment: In theory you could do the same thing with formulas, but you'd be shooting yourself in the foot: Perform the filter in the SQL and it gets handled before the report loads. You won't have to add extra suppression, grouping, null checkers, the works. Just rewrite the SQL and it will be a *lot* less work.

Comment: Thanks! This has been the simplest way to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very little information that you have provided and if i was to make a guess.I suggest you make use of the formula field in your report and then use something like this to accomplish your goal.

```
IF ISNULL{first_priority_field_name} OR {first_priority_field_name} = '' THEN 
{second_priority_field_name}
ELSE
{first_priority_field_name}
```

Use nested IF statement in case there are more than 2 identifier fields.

Comment: Thanks, but the field is never null or empty - I just wanted it to pick a certain value over another stored within the same field unless that value doesn't exist then pick the next one.